# Push Notification sent from Bluemix Dashboard not delivered to Cordova and Android Sample Apps

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, cordova-plugins, ibm-mobile-services

I signed up for a Bluemix account in the US-South region and created a CF mobile app to use the Push Notification Service. Added the GCM credentials to the push configuration, cloned both the Cordova and Android **HelloPush** sample apps from the **ibm-bluemix-mobile-services** repository and setup the App ID and App Routes in the index.js file (for Cordova) and the MainActivity class (for Android).

Followed the instructions in [Android helloPush Sample Application for Bluemix Mobile Services](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-hellopush) and [HelloPush Cordova application for IBM MobileFirst Services on IBM Bluemix](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-cordova-hellopush) for both the Android and Cordova apps respectively.

Although both the apps successfully register at the imfpush server and the token is received with the device id, the push messages sent via the Push Dashboard are not received by the apps.

Tried changing the GCM credentials, but no luck in resolving the issue.

I confirmed that the devices were registered in the Push Service by querying

```
https://imfpush.ng.bluemix.net/imfpush/v1/apps/{applicationId}/devices/
```

which returned the registered Device IDs.

Specifically, I noticed that `registerNotificationsCallback()` in the Cordova app does not get fired at any time.

Comment: Unable to recreate on my end and the fact that both platforms are not working for you would tend to lead me think the server isn't liking something in the config. It would help our investigation if you would provide the application ID so that we can look at our server logs (would also help to rerun the error scenario to populate the recent logs). The Application ID is intended to be public facing (App Secret is required to utilize actual Push notifications against the app), but if you feel uncomfortable posting it here I would invite you to create a support ticket through the Bluemix frontend.

Comment: May also want to note that it can take a few minutes for the first notification to come through after a fresh registration. I redid everything with a fresh clone from github and it took around 10 minutes to get the notifications I sent.

Comment: @JamesYoungIBM the Application ID is **8595d0b9-d6c7-406a-9151-6618f06025fa** and I did create a level 3 support ticket, but I didn't get a reply from your team

Answer (score 0):

We have recently pushed a number of updates to both our [Android Push SDK](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-android-push) and our [Cordova Push SDK](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-clientsdk-cordova-plugin-push) that hopefully have helped resolve this issue. We have also published an update to the [Android Hello Push](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-android-hellopush) sample that I would recommend retrying at this point.

Additionally please ensure the following

- That you are not using other push notification-related plugins in your Cordova project (phonegap for example) as these will cause conflicting behavior
- Your test device has access to the internet and can access Bluemix domains
- Your GCM credentials are push enabled and properly configured